# "Ошибка доступа для записи". В чём проблема?

Tags: c++, ассемблер

Написал простую программу с ассемблерной вставкой, использующую циклическую конструкцию:

```
// laba4.cpp: определяет точку входа для консольного приложения.
//

#include "stdafx.h"


int main()
{
int a, b, n;
cin >> n;
_asm {
    mov ebx, 1;
    mov ecx, n;
    dec ecx;
    mov ebp, 1;
    mov esi, 1;
    mov edi, -1;
loop_1:
    mov eax, edi;
    imul ebp;
    mov esp, eax;
    inc esi;
    mov eax, ebx;
    mul esi;
    mov ebx, eax;
    mov eax, ebp;
    mul esi;
    mov ebp, eax;
    add ebx, esp;
    neg edi;
    loop loop_1;
    mov a, ebx;
    mov b, ebp;
    }
    cout << a << "/" << b;
    return 0;
}
```

Так вот, при выполнении записи значений переменных из регистров (`mov a, ...; mov b, ...` возникает ошибка "Нарушение доступа для записи". Что здесь не так?

Comment: Ну, начать с того, что вы так вольно тронули такие регистры, как `esp` и `ebp`... И вообще, что вы, собственно, хотите посчитать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как минимум, не трогайте регистры `ebp` и `esp` - вы портите стековые указатели. Поскольку запись в переменные идет с использованием значения (безнадежно вами запорченного) регистра `ebp` - что-то типа

```
mov DWORD PTR _a$[ebp], ebx
mov DWORD PTR _b$[ebp], ebp
```

то вы и получаете ерунду.

Насколько верно то, что вы считаете - не знаю, но и тут у меня большие сомнения. Но это уже вопрос другой...

Comment: Попробовал закомментить строчки с `ebp` и  `esp`, однако ошибка осталась и исчезла только с комментированием строк с `esi` и `edi`.

Comment: Теперь другой вопрос. В задаче мне требуется вычислить сумму p/q = 1-1/2+1/3-…+(-1)^(n+1)/n для заданного числа n. Дробь p/q должна быть несократимой (p и q – натуральные). Препод рекомендовал не использовать вещественные числа и делать задачу с помощью целочисленных операций. Как мне решить эту задачу, ограничившись `eax, ebx, ecx, edx`?

Comment: Тут надо посидеть, а у меня сейчас просто нет времени на это. Если не справитесь или никто не подскажет до вечера - напомните, попробую глянуть.