# Найти сумму ряда дробей в виде p/q на ассемблере

Tags: ассемблер

Задача: вычислить сумму `p/q = 1-1/2+1/3-…+(-1)^(n+1)/n` для заданного числа n. Дробь `p/q` должна быть несократимой (`p` и `q` – натуральные). Препод рекомендовал не использовать вещественные числа и делать задачу с помощью целочисленных операций.

Вопрос: как это сделать? Я думал приблизительно так: у нас должны быть 4 числа `a`, `b`, `c` и `d` для представления соответственно дробей `a/b` и `с/d`. Тогда на каждом шаге мы должны вычислять сумму `(ad+bc)/bd`.

Алгоритм я себе представил приблизительно так:

1. Начальные значения: `a=1`,`b=1`,`c=-1`,`d=2`.
2. Вычислить `bd` и где-то сохранить, чтобы не затирать `b` и `d`.
3. Вычислить `ad`, сохранить так, чтобы не трогать `d`.
4. Вычислить `bc` и сохранить так, чтобы не трогать `c`.
5. Вычислить `ad+bc`.
6. `a=ad+bc, b=bd`
7. Сменить знак `c`.
8. Инкрементировать `d`.
9. Повторить 2-8 `n-1` раз.
10. Вычислить НОД получившихся p и q и разделить их на это число.

Попытки сделать это со всеми регистрами, которые есть в асме, привели вот к [этому](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/657795/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8-%D0%92-%D1%87%D1%91%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0).

Теперь вопрос: как сделать это, используя только `eax, ebx, ecx, edx`? Причём даже `ecx` и `edx`, по сути, отпадают, т. к. в `ecx` хранится счётчик цикла, а в `edx` - старшее слово результата умножения, которое затирается при умножении и должно быть равно 0 для дальнейших операций деления. Т. е. остаётся всего 2 регистра.

Comment: А зачем, простите, ограничения на использование регистров?

Comment: @VladD Так при использовании `ebp, esp, esi` и `edi` получаются ошибки. Или вы предлагаете делать постоянный обмен "регистр-память"?

Comment: Ну, если получаются ошибки, почему бы их не исправить?

Comment: Не вижу ничего особо плохого в обменах регистр-память, если что. В конце-концов, не зря ж у процессоров многоуровневый кэш. Но думаю, в вашей задаче можно обойтись без использования оперативки, да.

Comment: @VladD Так ошибки получаются потому, что эти регистры просто так использовать нельзя.

Comment: Эээ, а почему вдруг нельзя? Если они важны для окружающего кода, ну так положите их в стек и достаньте по окончанию вычислений, делов-то!

Comment: @VladD Ну, почему нельзя, в связанном вопросе вроде написано, нет?

Comment: Извините, не читал связанный вопрос. (Я думаю, имеет смысл внести все нужные данные в сам вопрос, потому что другим будет точно так же лень. Простите.)

Comment: Ну и да, если вы портите ebp, ну так сохраните его вначале и восстановите в конце. Чем этот рецепт плох? `push`/`pop` ведь не запрещены?

Comment: @VladD попробуем.

Comment: А esp трогать, понятно, нельзя. Если вы не знаете, почему, то всё очень плохо, и нужно читать теорию.

Comment: У вас код компилится как 32-битный ?

Comment: @Mike да. Это же ассемблерная вставка в VS.

Comment: @Byulent Ну я не в курсе про VS. он что ли генерит только 32 битный код. Мне казалось все компиляторы в наше время могут делать 64-битный код. особенно если система 64-битная

Comment: @Mike: А откуда, вы думаете, под Windows есть 64-битные программы? ;-P

Comment: Напишите, скажем, на С. Попросите компилятор сгенерировать ассемблерный код. Посмотрите, подчистите напильничком, где надо...